# TypeError at /tasks/add 'set' object is not reversible

Tags: python, list, set, typeerror

I'm getting this type of error: TypeError at /tasks/add
'set' object is not reversible. It occurred after I added a django link to an html file. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qSeZ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/floVw.png)

I looked it up on the Internet, and it says to change {} to [], but I immediately used []. Why? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3oqh.png)

Comment: Your variable is `url_patterns`.  The variable in the error message is `urlpatterns`.  These have nothing to do with each other.  The similarity of names is a coincidence. What did run to get this error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode